# How to use search option in bazaarvoice api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, sdk

We are trying to search the Reviews using Filter and Filter_[Type] option but unsuccessful and there is lack of examples in tutorial for this.

Please guide us. We had tried following things

```
http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?callback=?&apiversion=4.9&include=products,authors&filter=IsRatingsOnly:true&filter=DisplayLocale:en_US&passkey=kuy3zj9pr3n7i0wxajrzj04xo&limit=5
```

Using above URL we are filtering only the reviews given with rating

We are trying to filter ReviewText,Title Tags. we tried following url listed below

```
http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?callback=?&apiversion=4.9&include=products,authors&filter=ReviewText:this is a test&filter=DisplayLocale:en_US&passkey=kuy3zj9pr3n7i0wxajrzj04xo&limit=5 

http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?callback=?&apiversion=4.9&include=products,authors&filter_[Reviews]=ReviewText:this is a test&filter=DisplayLocale:en_US&passkey=kuy3zj9pr3n7i0wxajrzj04xo&limit=5 

http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?callback=?&apiversion=4.9&include=products,authors&filter=tag_ReviewText:Morbi bibendum&passkey=kuy3zj9pr3n7i0wxajrzj04xo&limit=5
```

We are unsuccessful on trying above URL.

Please guide us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `search="search_text"` attribute while passing data to json to search all the reviews.